# Pointcut matching all methods with a custom annotation

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@AspectJ pointcut for all methods of a class with specific annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation)

I am trying to write a pointcut for all methods of a class which have a custom annotation. Here's the code

- Annotation:

  ```
  import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
  import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
  import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
  import java.lang.annotation.Target;

  @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
  public @interface ValidateRequest {}
  ```
- Method in Controller:

  ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "getAbyB", produces = "application/json")
   @ResponseBody
   @ValidateRequest
   public Object getAbyB(@RequestBody GetAbyBRequest req) throws Exception { 
       /// logic
   }
  ```
- Aspect:

  ```
   @Aspect
   @Component
   public class CustomAspectHandler {
       @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
       public void foo(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           LOG.info("yippee!");
       }
   }
  ```
- applicationContext:

  ```
  `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`
  ```

I've been trying various advices, mentioned below, but none seem to work (except for the one used above)

- `@Around("@within(com.pack.Anno1) || @annotation(com.pack.Anno1)")`
- `@Around("execution(@com.pack.Anno1 * *(..))")`

Comment: Had been trying different pointcuts for two days and none of them worked. Moved the controller logic as such to service layer and kept custom annotation to service layer only. It worked. Not sure why so.. any clues?

Comment: It does't work because <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> does JDK Dynamic Proxies which only intercepts methods defined on an interface. I assume your Controller does not have an interface (normally they don't), so none of the methods on your Controller are intercepted. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-autoproxy-force-CGLIB

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 @Aspect
 @Component
 public class CustomAspectHandler {
    @Pointcut("execution(@ValidateRequest * *.*(..))")
    public void validateRequestTargets(){}

     @Around("validateRequestTargets()")
     public Object foo(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
         LOG.info("yippee!");
         return joinPoint.proceed();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try this before posting? I have the similar problem in my case  and the aspect is never being executed. I post a new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279716/error-at-0-cant-find-referenced-pointcut-annotation