# error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to create an aspect to monitor the time execution of certain methods. When I tried to run the test I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut annotation
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
```

when the ApplicationContext is loading.

I define the annotation as:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(
{
    ElementType.METHOD, 
    ElementType.TYPE
})
public @interface TimePerformance {

}
```

And this is the aspect code:

```
@Aspect
public class MonitorImpl{

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MonitorImpl.class);


    @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() { }



    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && annotation(timePerformance)")
    public Object  timePerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,TimePerformance timePerformance) throws Throwable {

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
             LOG.info("AOP - Before executing "+pjp.getSignature());
        }

        Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object result = pjp.proceed();

        Long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        LOG.info("MONITOR TIME_EXECUTION "+pjp.getSignature()+" : "+(stopTime-startTime));

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
             LOG.info("AOP - After  executing "+pjp.getSignature());
        }

        return result;

    }


}
```

And the configuration is:

```
<!-- AOP support -->
<bean id='stateAspectImpl' class='eu.genetwister.snpaware.ui.aspect.StateAspectImpl' />
 <bean id='monitorImpl' class='eu.genetwister.snpaware.monitor.MonitorImpl' />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name='stateAspectImpl' />
     <aop:include name='monitorImpl' />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

I just checked many questions here, but most of them gives as solution use the version 1.7 of aspectj. I am using:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Other solution point to the name of the variable in the method signature, but as you can see there is no error on that.

Does anyone any idea about where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem using this configuration in the aspect class

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(timePerformance)")
public Object  timePerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, TimePerformance timePerformance) throws Throwable
```

But the problem now, the aspect is not being executed.

Answer (score 12):

You are simply missing a `@` in front of `annotation` in your pointcut.

```
@Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(timePerformance)")
                              ^
```