# @AspectJ Class level Annotation Advice with Annotation as method argument

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

How can I get the annotation to be passed as the argument for the Advice defined for 
class-level annotation? Is it possible?

From the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation/2522821) I am able to get the point cut that identifies all the public method in the class which is marked by a specific Annotation. I am able to get the advice applied as well. However, I don’t know how to get the annotation variable passed as argument in above case.

For a method-level annotation, I am able to get the pointcut and advice in which I can get the annotation passed as argument, but I don’t know how to achieve the same for class-level annotation.

The below code works, but I need to get the annotation as the argument for the advice “**LogExecutionTimeByClass**” in below program and I couldn’t able to get appropriate advice or pointcut for the same.

Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
String level();
}
```

Aspect:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LogTimeAspect {

    /*
     * Pointcut to match all the public methods.
    */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}

    /*
     * Advice for the public methods that are marked with Annotation "LogExecutionTime" and it works as expected no issue.
    */ 
    @Around("publicMethod() && @annotation(annotation) ")
    public Object LogExecutionTimeByMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,final LogExecutionTime annotation) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Invoking the method " +joinPoint.getSignature() +" by LogExecutionTimeByMethod Advice");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }


    /*
     * Pointcut to match all the public methods that are defined under the Class marked with Annotation LogExecutionTime.
    */
    @Pointcut("within(@LogExecutionTime *)")
    public void beanAnnotatedWithMonitor() {}

    @Pointcut("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithMonitor()")
    public void publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithAtMonitor() {}

    /*
     * Below Advice works but I need the LogExecutionTime annotation as an argument to below method. (similar to the advice "LogExecutionTimeByMethod" 
     * defined above)
    */
    @Around("publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithAtMonitor()")
    public Object LogExecutionTimeByClass(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Invoking the method " +joinPoint.getSignature() +" by  LogExecutionTimeByClass Advice");
        //System.out.println("Invoked by " + annotation.value()); //Need the Annotation Variable here as well...
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

/*
    */
}
```

Annotated Class:

```
@LogExecutionTime(level="Class_Level_Invocation")
public class Operator {

    @LogExecutionTime(level="Method_Level_Invocation")
    public void operate()  throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public void operate1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Main Program:

```
public class AspectJMain {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Operator op = new Operator();
            op.operate();
            op.operate1();
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Invoking the method void Operator.operate() by LogExecutionTimeByMethod Advice
Invoking the method void Operator.operate() by  LogExecutionTimeByClass Advice
Invoking the method void Operator.operate1() by  LogExecutionTimeByClass Advice
```

Please note that using Spring is is not an option. I have to use AspectJ compiler.
I compiled my classes and packaged them as jar and use ApsectJ compiler to woven the aspect using below command.

ajc -inpath core.jar -outjar ..\lib\core_woven.jar -1.5

Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple. I am writing my code in native AspectJ style, I prefer it for clarity. You will be easily able to adjust it to @AspectJ annotation style:

```java
public aspect LogTimeAspect {
    pointcut publicMethod() : execution(public * *(..));

    before(LogExecutionTime logAnn) : publicMethod() && @annotation(logAnn) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> " + logAnn.level());
    }

    before(LogExecutionTime logAnn) : publicMethod() && @within(logAnn) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> " + logAnn.level());
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
execution(void Operator.operate()) -> Method_Level_Invocation
execution(void Operator.operate()) -> Class_Level_Invocation
execution(void Operator.operate1()) -> Class_Level_Invocation
```

As you can see,

- there is no need for `around()` advice, `before()` is sufficient unless you want to manipulate any parameters or block the captured method executions,
- you can bind the annotations in question via `@annotation()` or `@within()` to named parameters if you just use the correct syntax.

Enjoy! `:-)`

---

**Update:** Here is the @AspectJ version of the aspect for your convenience and because you seemed to have problems adapting my solution from the native syntax:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LogTimeAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}

    @Around("publicMethod() && @annotation(logAnn)")
    public Object LogExecutionTimeByMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogExecutionTime logAnn) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + logAnn.level());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @Around("publicMethod() && @within(logAnn)")
    public Object LogExecutionTimeByClass(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogExecutionTime logAnn) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + logAnn.level());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

The results will be identical to my original version.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try out. The reason for Around is to get the execution time of the method.

Comment: I tried but not able to pass in annotation argument via within but below point cut works @Pointcut("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithMonitor() && @annotation(annotation)")

Comment: You really do not need `beanAnnotatedWithMonitor()`, see my update above.