# Spring @AspectJ @Pointcut to match regardless of argument list

Tags: eclipse, spring, aop, aspectj, pointcut

How do I write a Spring @AspectJ point-cut (`@Pointcut`) expression that matches all public methods in a class, regardless of their argument list?

I want an aspect that has `@AfterThrowing` point-cuts for *all* the public methods of a particular class that have a particular annotation, `@MyAnnotation` (similar to what someone else wanted in [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation)). At present my aspect is like this:

```
 @Aspect
 public final class ServiceDataAccessExceptionReporter {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.example.Service.*(..)) && @annotation(com.example.MyAnnotation))")
    public void annotatedMethod() {}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "annotatedMethod()", throwing = "exception")
    public void reportException(final DataAccessException exception) {
       ...
    }
 }
```

The **Eclipse Spring plug-in** indicates (using arrow annotations in the source-code windows) this as correctly advising a method `com.example.Service.getNames()`. But it does not indicate that methods that have arguments, such as `com.example.Service.getTimes(String name)`, have been advised.

Is that because the method with the `@Pointcut` annotation has no arguments? How can I make the point-cut be all methods, regardless of their argument list? Or must I have a separate `@Pointcut` for each kind of argument list in my `com.example.Service` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the resulting WAR shows that the aspect is, in fact working, and that all the methods of my service class that I want to be point cuts are point cuts.

I conclude that this is actually a flaw in the Eclipse Spring plug-in: it does not show all the join points when a `@Pointcut` matches multiple locations, but instead shows only one, which it chooses somewhat arbitrarily.