# @AspectJ pointcut for all methods inside package

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have this working code for a specific package, but i want to configure it for all **controllers**, **service** and **dao** packages
Eg

- com.abc.xyz.content.controller
- com.abc.xyz.content.service
- com.abc.xyz.content.dao
- com.abc.xyz.category.controller
- com.abc.xyz.category.service
- com.abc.xyz.category.dao

and so on. . .
 that is the base package of my project, can someone please help how I can go about doing it so that it works for all classes of my web project including controllers, thanks in advance. 
. .

```
package com.abc.xyz.utilities;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect
{
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.abc.xyz.content.service..*(..))")
    protected void loggingOperation()
    {
    }

    @Before("loggingOperation()")
    @Order(1)
    public void logJoinPoint(JoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
    log.info("Signature declaring type : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    log.info("Signature name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    log.info("Arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    log.info("Target class : " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "loggingOperation()", returning = "result")
    @Order(2)
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result)
    {
    log.info("Exiting from Method :" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    log.info("Return value :" + result);
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.abc.xyz.content.service..*(..))", throwing = "e")
    @Order(3)
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e)
    {
    log.error("An exception has been thrown in " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
    log.error("Cause :" + e.getCause());
    }

    @Around("execution(* com.abc.xyz.content.service..*(..))")
    @Order(4)
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
    log.info("The method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() begins with " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    try
    {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        log.info("The method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() ends with " + result);
        return result;
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        log.error("Illegal argument " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()) + " in " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
        throw e;
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

How about one of these alternatives?

**A) General execution pointcut with package restrictions:**

```java
execution(* *(..)) &&
(
    within(com.abc.xyz..controller..*) ||
    within(com.abc.xyz..service..*) ||
    within(com.abc.xyz..dao..*)
)
```

**B) Package-restricted execution pointcuts:**

```java
execution(* com.abc.xyz..controller..*(..)) ||
execution(* com.abc.xyz..service..*(..)) ||
execution(* com.abc.xyz..dao..*(..))
```

I prefer B, by the way, just because it is a bit shorter and easier to read. As you have probably guessed, the `..` notation means "any package or subpackage", whereas `*` at the end of the expression after `..` means "any method in any class".

Comment: So basically it is possible to define all `within()` pointcut expressions using other pointcut desginators, right? I think for nested classes, `within()` can simplify the expressions (sometimes _extremely_), but otherwise it is just a convenient pointcut designator.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it often just does not make sense. I would always choose the (combination of) pointcut(s) most clearly expressing my intent as a developer. Good pointcuts can be read like a sentence such as: "Within packages x and y, pick all public, non-static methods in classes annotated by @Z, but only if they return values of type A."

Comment: Late amendment to my previous comment: `within` matches many more joinpoint types than just `execution`, e.g. `call`, `get`, `set`, `initialization`, `staticinitialization`. It also matches constructor execution which has different syntax than method execution when using `execution` pointcuts.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to change your point cut to something like this :

```
@Pointcut("within(com.abc.*)")
```

Further reading - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: Okay. For controllers you can do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/xyz-web-vodafone/content.showContentWorkbench.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: firstly can I atleast configure it for services and dao packages, can U tell me how to achieve that

Comment: Its pretty simple. What you need to do is provide expression within @Pointcut itself as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use

```
@Pointcut("bean(*Controller)")
```

But naming of your beans should be corresponding