# Save method is intercepted but findAll is not

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

The problem is simple

```
@Around("execution(* package.*Repository.save(..))")
public Object saveInterupt(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // This gets called whenever repository save is called
}

@Around("execution(* package.*Repository.findAll(..))")
public Object findInterupt(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // This IS NOT GETTING called whenever repository findAll is called
}
```

Breaking head here!

Edit: A small breakthrough. I printed the target, it returned `SimpleJpaRepository` instead of the actual repository.

Comment: Brief as the question, fail to solve after a day debug. Headache!

Comment: The method `findAll` and `save` from `CrudRepository` is implemented default in `SimpleJpaRepository`. So `*Repository` is a jdk dynamic proxy that in honour of `SimpleJpaRepository` in runtime.

Comment: @Lebecca so how do I log the actual calling class?

Comment: You can set a breakPoint in the `SimpleJpaRepository save() or getAll()` methods, and run the application in debug mode to prove my words. The key point is not the inner object, it's the invocation chain that the proxy executes before the inner object method gets called. Spring uses some cache for building the chain makes it a mysterious for me why `findAll` not get enhanced.

Comment: @Around("execution(* org..*Repository.save(..)) and @Around("execution(* org..*Repository.findAll(..)) works for me all the time. If you want to intercept at a package level , pointcut designators within && execution could be combined.

Comment: Could you please provide clarity on the "package" used within @Around("execution(* package.*Repository.save(..))") .

Comment: @R.G There is a [demo](https://github.com/LangInteger/spring-aop-demo) where I face the same problem with madhairsilence.

Comment: @Lebecca On a quick look , you are setting @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) . This enables CGLIB-style 'subclass' proxies and not the default interface-based JDK proxy. This is the primary and most important difference between our testcases. You may set it to false or remove the attribute which is equivalent to setting it to false and rerun the testcases.

Comment: @R.G Thanks for your suggestions. The abnormal config is just a try, but CGLIB/JDK proxy doesn't make a difference in my test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203726/discussion-between-lebecca-and-r-g).

Comment: @Lebecca , adding for future reference : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24207

Comment: The main issue is your pointcut. The method isn't defined on your interface, rather a super interface. You should write a pointcut on that hierachy something like `org.springframework.data.jpa.CrudRepository+.save(..)`, notice the `+` which is key here. If you want to limit within your own package then add an `within('your.package)` to the expression.

Comment: @M.Deinum so why does it work for one method but not for other

Comment: Did you override/added the `save` method to your own interface?

Comment: No. I have additional methods but no requirement to override default save/find method

Answer (score 2):

This issue is the same as [Spring issue 27761](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27761) and was solved in AspectJ 1.9.20.1, see also [AspectJ issue 256](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/issues/256).

The root cause was related to bridge methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the repository is of the following construct

```
public interface JpaEmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<JpaEmployee, Long> {..}
```

following pointcut works on both the cases

```
@Around("execution(* org..*Repository.save(..))")
```

and

```
@Around("execution(* org..*Repository.findAll(..))")
```

If I understand the question correctly the requirement is to intercept on the execution of a particular method within a specific package.If yes, More details on the same can be read here.
[@AspectJ pointcut for all methods inside package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992277/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-inside-package/26005838)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Spring-BOOT ? Aspecting in Spring-BOOT only calls the advice on a single method in the class the first time it is called. If you want Spring-BOOT to respect your @Around advice in all cases for multiple methods in any given class -- you need to access the class as a bean (SB's @Bean)...

Spring-BOOT's AOP is not 100% the same as aspecting using AspectJ -- the main difference is AspectJ modifies the byte-code where Spring uses a dynamic proxy.