# I am trying to make a pointcut. but its giving an Exception

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, pointcut

here i am using a point cut annotation as follows:

```
    @Pointcut("Execution(* com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.*.*(..))")
    private void forControllerPackage() {
        
    }
```

it giving me an exception  which is as:

```
Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 12
Execution(* com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.*.*(..))
            ^^^
```

I have just started learning AOP any suggestion or help is going to help a lot thanks.

Comment: Hi Please have look of this thread, this might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992277/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-inside-package/26005838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spell `execution` in all lower-case characters:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.*.*(..))")
private void forControllerPackage() {}
```

BTW, if you want to make sure that subpackages of `com.luv2code.springdemo.controller` are also covered, please use the `..` syntax as follows:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.luv2code.springdemo.controller..*(..))")
private void forControllerPackage() {}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a better (as in more flexible) pointcut variant.