# Spring extend Authentication object to keep controller dry

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
public List<MyObject> find( Authentication auth )
      //read details off the authentication object.
      OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauthDetails= (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
      HashMap<String, Object> additionalInformationMap = ( HashMap<String, Object> )oauthDetails.getDecodedDetails();
```

I currently have a small bit of code in my controller that reads additional information stored in a JWT token.

Preferably I would not like to write this code in multiple controller methods- chances are it would be peppered throughout the codebase.

Is there a better way of doing this in Spring that isn't in the controller. e.g. can I extend the Authentication object in a filter or something and add that extra data to a public method on the extended object?

Edit. from reading around, it appears that AOP potentially would solve this problem. Just not sure where to start

Comment: You only plan to use this in some, not all controller methods? If so, you can create a custom annotation, and use AOP to execute a method for all methods (or classes) annotated with your custom annotation

Comment: @JabariDash - yes, that is a beautifully elegant solution - I'm going that very route as we speak - just struggling to populate the method args with AOP.

Comment: I'll find an implementation I have to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an annotation that can be applied to methods and classes. If it is applied to a class, the annotation simply cascades and applies to all methods in the class.

```
package com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Component
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NoNullArgs {
}
```

Then create a class with an advice (method to apply) to a series of point cuts (locations to apply the actual advice). **Note. This is an example implemented in Groovy that merely checks that all arguments are not null. However, you can change the body of the method to do whatever you want.** Once you have the `args` array, those are the values that you can cast to the the expected type.

```
package com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.aspect

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Aspect
@Order(0)
@Component
class NoNullArgsAspect {

    // Use this if writing in Java.
    // omitting the getMetaClass call is only for Groovy

    // @Before(
    //         value = "@within(com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.annotation.NoNullArgs) || @annotation(com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.annotation.NoNullArgs)"
    // )

    @Before(
            value = "!execution(* *.getMetaClass(..)) && @within(com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.annotation.NoNullArgs) || @annotation(com.perfectcomputersolutions.pos.annotation.NoNullArgs)"
    )
    void requireNotNull(JoinPoint jp) {

        def method = (CodeSignature) jp.signature
        def types  = method.parameterTypes
        def names  = method.parameterNames
        def args   = jp.args

        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++)
            Objects.requireNonNull(args[i], "Parameter ${names[i]} must not be null" as String)
    }
}
```

- See [original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation)
- See [Spring AOP Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)